# how to mutate inputting array in-place in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Recently I have a piece of code like this:

```
private func a(var arr1: [Int]) {
    arr1.removeRange(0..<2)
}
```

I thought that adding "var" to arr1 makes it mutable. I eventually notice it's not mutating the inputting array "arr1" after debugging for three hours. I then tried to add the keyword "mutating" to the function, but this gives an error:
    'mutating' isn't valid on methods in classes or class-bound protocols

So what is the correct way of mutating arr1 in-place inside the function a()? Is adding "mutating" to the func the way to go? If so, how do I resolve the error message? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Array` of `Int` is a value type, that means the object is copied while being passed to the method.

You can declare the `arr1` parameter as `inout`, that treats the array as reference type:

```
private func a(inout arr1: [Int]) {
  arr1.removeRange(0..<2)
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a(&array)
print(array) // [3, 4]
```

or you have to return the changed array:

```
private func a(var arr1: [Int]) -> [Int] {
  arr1.removeRange(0..<2)
  return arr1
}

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let result = a(array)
print(result) // [3, 4]
```